# How can I get data from Firebase continuously within a loop and the data should be checked inside in it , if data is incorrect loop should be exited

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The loop is designed to get the data continuously until the value of database is changed,but on giving loop to get data continuously from Firebase doesn't working.

The first we have to fetch the current location and this works perfectly.

```
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            try {
                //value of latitude is copied to latit
                String latit = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                //value of longitude is copied to longi
                String longi = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

                l1 = Double.valueOf(latit);
                l2 = Double.valueOf(longi);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lati" + l1 + "and longi" + l2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

By executing this code I got the current data from Firebase realtime database

And below show the code that doesn't work for me.

```
                        while(n==1) {
                        mDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                            mDatabase1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String latit1 = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                                    //value of longitude is copied to longi
                                    String longi1 = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

                                    l3 = Double.valueOf(latit1);
                                    l4 = Double.valueOf(longi1);
                                    //the below code is for showing a notification.
```

here l1 and l3 is latitudes and l2 and l4 are longitudes.l1 and l3 are declared above.

```
                                    if (!(l1.equals(l3) && l2.equals(l4))) {
                                        createChannels();
                                        String title = "Danger";
                                        String content = "Your Vehicle has been moved";
                                        Notification.Builder builder = getEDMTChannelNotification(title, content);
                                        getManager().notify(new Random().nextInt(), builder.build());
                                        n = 0;
                                        //n set to zero and loop exit when notification is shown.
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }

                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put this check inside an essentially infinite loop. The `ValueEventListener`, once set, automatically fires every time there is a change in the reference you're looking at. So you simply have to set the listener and it'll always fire as long as the app is open.

[Example from docs:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```